# Java Spring does not map HTML templates

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on a Spring project with Gradle, I use mysql-connector-java *v-8.0.30*, javax.persistence-api *v-2.2*, and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependencies. My project was running correctly, but from one moment to another it stopped compiling, only the Spring logo appears in the console with the following warning: **RN 19232 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning**

[image]

What I thought at first is that the application was not compiling, however when I access it, I execute a class method annotated with @RestController and I paint a message in the HTMl, it is displayed correctly.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
   public class CompraventaspringApplication {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CompraventaspringApplication.class, args);
       }

       @GetMapping("/")
       public static String message(@RequestParam(value = "saludo", defaultValue =
       "i'm a CRUD system") String saludo )
       {
          return String.format("<h1>Hello  %s ! </h1>", saludo);
       }
```

[image]

However, when I try to bind any route from a controller to an HTML template the route doesn't map properly. I've already tried to remove the Gradle dependencies and rebuild them but still can't find my HTML:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class ControllerProductos {
    @Autowired
    public ProductoServicesClass service;

    public static String UPLOADS = "src/main/resources/static/uploads";

    // Listar todos los productos diponibles
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String listar(Model model) {
        List<Productos> productos = service.listar();

        model.addAttribute("productos", productos);

        return "HomePage";
    }
 }
```

[image]

I already checked several times and yes, the name of the template is the same as the one associated with the return of the method.

Comment: When you get this whitelabel error what error msg you see on console? Share it here. You must be missing/wrongly-handling some object(s) in your html/view.

Comment: The error will occur after associating the list method to the template. As indicated in the post, I do not receive any other errors, the lines that appear in my console are the same as those added in the publication, it is as if all my program is separated from each other, although I already checked and all my packages are correctly accompanied to the claspath